# Nested Data Breakdown in CSV to SPSS

Tags: csv, spss

I am new to the SPSS platform and i got a complicated dataset to work with in SPSS.

The data look like this

```
header1|header2|header3|{header4_a - header4_b - header4_c} |{header5_a - header5_b - header5_c} |{header6_a - header6_b - header6_c} 
1|some-text-can be here| 2 |{ Alex - John,Doe - 20}|{ Maria - Maria,Doe - 300}
2|some-other text| 1 |{ Mike- Mike,Doe - 400}
```

I would love some guidance how to open this file so i can work on each header4_a header4_b etc separately.

Comment: Would be glad to help but need more clarification about the present structure of your data and where you'd like to get too. Also it might be helpful if you could post some sample data.

Comment: @eli-k thanks for replying first of all. I just want to breakdown the csv using the pipe (|) and hyphen (-) as delimiters while removing the curly braces ( { , } ) but ignoring any hyphens under header 2. Will edit my original post to add a line of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the file using only the pipes as delimiters. Headers 4a-4c will be read into a single variable (the same with 5a-5c) which will be easy to separate into 3 variables as you described.

Use syntax along these lines:

```
*first creating some fake data to experiment on.
data list list/header4(a30).
begin data
"{Alex - John,Doe - 5005}"
"{ Maria - Maria,Doe - 300}"
end data.

* now cleaning and dividing `header4`.
string header4_a header4_b header4_c (a20).

compute header4=replace(replace(header4,"{",""),"}","").

compute header4_a=char.substr(header4,1,char.index(header4,"-")-1).
compute header4_b=char.substr(header4,char.index(header4,"-")+1).
compute header4_c=char.substr(header4_b,char.index(header4_b,"-")+1).
compute header4_b=char.substr(header4_b,1,char.index(header4_b,"-")-1).
exe.
```

Comment: ty for helping out. I am stuck with this error though >Warning # 651 
>The third argument to the CHAR.SUBSTR function is invalid. 
>Command line: 167  Current case: 1  Current splitfile group: 1

The data become from {Alex - John,Doe - 5005} to  Alex  | John,Doe-500  | 5005  (pipes are to indicate columns)

Comment: I corrected a typo and added some sample data - the code now seems to work - give it a try.

Comment: getting the same error message for some reason but at least this time all data split perfectly so i will accept it as answered. Thanks again on my first steps with SPSS

Comment: since i am a newbie and didnt want to make a new question but now that i splited the data i want to plot one bar chart combining all header4_b.header5_b etc data. Looking something that will copy all header4_b data to new var b then directly below will ad the data from 5_b etc etc. Really grateful for the time spend.

Comment: sounds like you need to work with `varstocases`, but indeed you should post a new question.

Comment: thanks again. will start googlin since varstocases didnt come up with what i was looking and if i get stuck i will make a new question. thanks again